# Reference request: Cut-and-project method gives rise to a fiber bundle over the torus

Tags: reference-request, fibre-bundles, tiling

I apologize in advance for how vague this request is.

A few weeks ago, I came upon a paper that (if I recall correctly) proves that **the hull of a cut-and-project tiling is a fiber bundle over a torus**. This is *not* the paper by Sadun cited below, but rather it specifically deals with cut-and-project tilings. If I recall correctly, it was published in a journal of physics, or the author was a physicist. I don't recall the name being one of the "big names" in tiling spaces (like Bellisard, Forrest, Hunton, Kellendonk, Putnam, etc.). I am interested mainly in the methods that they used in the paper, and not the result itself. Sadly, the computer on which I found the paper died shortly after I found it and I lost everything related to that paper. I have no author name, no paper title, and very vague search terms to go off of in my hunt.

Edit: it might be that the result I'm thinking of is actually related to something with bounded displacement rather than the hull being a fiber bundle.

Does anyone happen to have any idea what paper this might be?

***References***

*Sadun, Lorenzo; Williams, R. F.*, [**Tiling spaces are Cantor set fiber bundles.**](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385702000949), Ergodic Theory Dyn. Syst. 23, No. 1, 307-316 (2003). [ZBL1038.37014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1038.37014).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the sought-after paper. It was *Duneau, M., and Christophe O.* "Displacive transformations and quasicrystalline symmetries." Journal de Physique 51.1 (1990): 5-19.

In section 3, they show that a cut and project pattern can be mapped onto a lattice by what they call (but never define) a "modulation".

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for

Martin Schlottmann, "Generalized model sets and dynamical systems", In: "Directions in Mathematical Quesicrystals", M. Baake, R. Moody (eds.).

In section 4, he proves the following: given any cut-and-project scheme $(G, H, \mathcal{L})$, and any regular (i.e. boundary measure zero) aperiodic window $W$, there exists a mapping $\alpha$ from the hull $\mathbb X$ of $\Lambda(W)$ to the torus $\mathbb T= (G \times H)/\mathcal{L}$ with the following properties:

- $\alpha$ is continuous and commutes with the $G$-action.
- $\alpha$ is almost surely 1-1.

In other words, $(\mathbb X, G)$ is an almost 1-1 extension of $\mathbb T$.

**P.S.** This is also explained, and extended beyond regular windows in:

G. Keller, C. Richard, "Dynamics on the graph of the torus parametrization", Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems , Volume 38 , Issue 3 , May 2018 , pp. 1048 - 1085
[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1017/etds.2016.53)

Comment: Thank you for the ideas! Neither of these ended up being the paper I was looking at earlier, but I wouldn't be surprised if they give me some of the insights I was looking for in the "missing" paper.

Comment: @Kyle Very unlikely, but your comment about "bounded displacement" may be related to somethink like this https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09789 or https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02514

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, revisiting some of the references in these papers just helped me find the actual paper!